# Pytesseract OCR running from memory and ignoring the current file. How to fix it?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, pyautogui

I am doing some OCR on scanned documents.

I used this OCR code (pytesseract) million times and it works like a charm. I run it on jupyter notebook. So I decided to automate it using pyautogui. The code works fine. I did the test run at the end of last week. Everything worked as expected so I left it there.

Today I ran it to do an actual work. My images are named as 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc. The output is going to be a bunch of numbers.

The first image, 0.jpg,  had 8 floating point numbers and I got something completely different while the other 2 pages output was accurate. I realized the 0.jpg output was the same as my last week's trial run as if it was run from memory/cache and not from the input today.

I tried to clear the kernel and outputs. Nothing changed. I went to the folder and manually deleted the old kernels. Nothing changed. I tried to run the code manually, without the help of pyautogui, even though I think that was not the issue. Nothing changed. In the end I decided to delete that picture (0.jpg) and then ran the code. Instead of giving me a "file not found" or "no such file" type error it gave me the same output. Just to make it clear, in the last attempt I had no file named 0.jpg and tried to perform OCR on 0.jpg and got the output from last week.

I don't know what I need to clear here to get the code to work properly. I didn't think it was a browser issue so didn't clear browser cache. But tried everything else I could think of.

Any idea what I should try to fix?

Thanks

Comment: Strange.. My gut instinct is that it is NOT 'running from memory' and something else is going on. If you are using relative file paths to reference your pictures, maybe try printing out the current working directory and sanity check yourself to make sure you aren't working in some old copy of your images. If you just display the 0.jpg using opencv or pillow, does it still show you the old image?

Comment: My images folder had only 3 images and I made sure everything else was deleted. Also, as I mentioned, the last attempt stumped me. That is when I had no file yet got the same result. But I will try to display the image with pillow and see what I get. Thanks for taking the time to answer.